# error 500 al acceder al link de cambio de contrasena con django allauth

Tags: django

Tengo una aplicacion (en produccion) con django 4.2 + postgresql, y estoy usando para el control de los usuarios django-allauth==0.54.0. Todo esto sobre un servidor linux ubunto 22.04 con gunicorn y nginx (con https)

Al ejecutar el proceso de recuperacion de password, en donde el usuario hace click en el formulario de login, en la opcin "olvide mi password"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar a la pantalla, se le pide un correo, y luego de dar click en ok, se le envia un correo que tiene el siguiente formato:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca hay un dato importante, y es que la URL que esta correctamente formada en su parte fija (https://xxxxxxxxxx.cl/accounts/password/reset/key)  ademas lleva 2 parametros.
Por una parte el uidb36 (que es 1 en este caso) y el key (que es brl752-f9faf0b526a88e51cdf550d14048eb8f).

Hasta ahi todo esta OK.
El problema, se da cuando el usuario hace click en el enlace, y se redirige a la URL indicada, aparece un error de servidor 500
Segun el log del sistema que esta en /var/log/syslog, el error seria que no se estan recibiendo los parametros correctamente cuando se intenta renderizar el archivo webscrap/templates/account/password_reset_from_key.html  que contiene el codigo html para presentar al usuario el ingreso de la nueva password

concretamente en :

```
<form action="{% url 'account_reset_password_from_key' uidb36=uidb36 key=key %}" method="post">
```

Este es el error que aparece en el log

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_reset_password_from_key' with keyword arguments '{'uidb36': '', 'key': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$']
```

aca el problema, no es la ruta resultante de la URL, si no que al parecer hay algo en el template html, que no parece encajar con los parametros que se le esta enviando.

Estuve investigando respecto de este proceso y llegue a las siguientes conclusiones:

1. el uidb36 es una codificacion del id del usuario que se establece para evitar que los enlaces URLs lleven directamente el id del isario en la base de datos
2. en la key, se da la misma codificacion, pero este valor se traduce en la cadena "set-password", y se usa para que en el codigo se pueda validar la accion.

como dato adicional, el sistema se autentica usando el username y password, y no el correo del usuario (no se si este dato tendra algo que ver)

Cualquier ayuda al respecto, se agradece de antemano
Saludos